# Does bolt-python take care of returning 302 to a slack URL for an app's direct install URL

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

When filling in details for my Slack app, I get `Your application's redirect URL must return a status code of 302 to a slack.com url` error on the direct install URL field (using the install URL `https://my-api-domain/slack/install` for the app):

[image]

I'm wondering if `bolt-python` takes care of this case or is this something that a developer needs to take care of themselves? And is this direct URL necessary for my Slack app?

Comment: Hey @Nashua Kang . How did you solve this? :) I'm stuck with this same situation.

Comment: It's been a while and I can't remember how I solved it. I think Suyash's comment gave me enough information. Sorry can't be of more help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation provided :

 https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#authenticating-oauth

> Bolt for Python will also create a slack/install route, where you can find an Add to Slack button for your app to perform direct installs of your app. If you need any additional authorizations (user tokens) from users inside a team when your app is already installed or a reason to dynamically generate an install URL, you can pass your own custom URL generator to oauth_settings as authorize_url_generator.